# Weird Jquery UI dialog box on MVC 4 ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So im trying to display a JQUERY UI dialog box just to show some stuff, ive viewing some tutorials and i finall got one that it kind of works, but it works weird, because it creates a strange result, what is what im doing wrong? im new with this MVC 4 and JQuery stuff.

[image: lol]

here is the code im using:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Exito";
}

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="message" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hola, Escribiste: ";
}



<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#message').dialog({

    });

</script>

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">


    var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: " + '@(ViewBag.Message)';

       var myLength = Texto.length;



       document.write("La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de "+myLength+" (Incluyendo el 'hola, escribiste')");



       </script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: do you have the css for the jquery ui dialog?

Comment: well i put this <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">, thats what you mean?

Comment: that may not have the right styles needed.

Comment: UM, that is not the normal name for the jquery ui stylesheet...

Comment: and what would be it, bro?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i solved it, the link was not pointing correctly to the css style.

it was

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

noob mistake